# Taking the conversation furher?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction

I want to tell the employees in my company that I don't want them to chat about some subjects at our work website. And also that I dont want them to go other platforms either to talk about this (like email or chat apps on the phone). In a somewhat formal way.

Can I say "by taking the conversation to other websites or chat apps"? Is it correct to say "by taking the conversation".
Or is it better to say something like "by going to other platforms to talk about this". Or something else?

Comment: You can say: "What happens inside our company is confidential. Please respect that."

Comment: futher, what you have written is  something else.

Comment: "take this somewhere else" or "take this conversation somewhere else" are common in English, but I'm not sure why you would say that as you don't want them talking at all

Comment: @Lambie While no further, your word is no closer.